# Uncaught TypeError: styled_default is not a function at Grid2.js:5:26

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid, vite

I am having problem with material ui library when I try to run react with vite.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9i2O.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pxvm.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B4iW.png)

I tried deleting and reinstalling the node_modules folder several times. But it didn't work. Even when I installed an older version of the Material UI library, I didn't get any results. But the project was working a day ago.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32727#issuecomment-1553100858. This may help.

Answer (score -2):

Let try: npm run dev --force

That works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).