# Unable to use Grid2 with Vite project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having an issue with MUI Grid2 in my Vite project. I get the following in my in my console:

```
Grid2.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: styled_default is not a function
at Grid2.js:5:26
```

I noticed that there was a similar post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213917/uncaught-typeerror-styled-default-is-not-a-function-at-grid2-js526`, but didn't notice any real answers for the problem.

My Package.json: Thought that there might have been an import issue, but I don't notice anything out of the ordinary.

```
    {
    "name": "workoutjournal",
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "tsc && vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@fontsource/staatliches": "^5.0.1",
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
        "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
        "@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
        "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.11",
        "eslint": "^8.37.0",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
        "install": "^0.13.0",
        "npm": "^9.6.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.9",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@svgr/cli": "^8.0.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "postcss": "^8.4.24",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "typescript": "^5.0.3",
        "vite": "^4.2.0"
    }
}
```

I've also deleted my node_modules and ran yarn install, but to no avail.
This is my import for it, `import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2';`
How I am trying to use it:

```
 <Grid
                container
                spacing={2}
                columns={16}
            >
                <Grid xs={8}>
                    <Item>xs=8</Item>
                </Grid>
                <Grid xs={8}>
                    <Item>xs=8</Item>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

I've used it in the past with CRA, but this is the first time I've tried to use it with Vite. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try importing Grid2 this way:

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2/Grid2';
```

Per GH discussion: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32727#issuecomment-1563834184

Comment: If you have restricted-imports rule for eslint, this also works for me in Vite + MUI 5.15: `import { Unstable_Grid2 as Grid2 } from "@mui/material";`